# "May have been" : sequence of tenses

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, sequence-of-tenses

Let us suppose we have such a sentence:

> John says Marry may have fallen ill.

How should we change the sentence if we talk about the past?
Is it correct?

> John said Marry might have fallen ill.

And what about `can` and  `must`?

And also I am curious about `might` in the past, that is `may`, but with less certainty. That is `might have been` in the present expresses lesser probability than `may`. Can we convey this subtlety in the past somehow?

Comment: 44 views and no answer so far...either the question is stupid or I am unlucky

Comment: I think you must mean [**Mary**](http://www.behindthename.com/name/mary), to *marry* is a verb. I don't think I have ever heard a woman called Marry, although nowadays anything is possible.

Comment: related: [Past tense of “must” when meaning logical probability](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36521/past-tense-of-must-when-meaning-logical-probability?rq=1), [“Might have” vs “could have”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64374/might-have-vs-could-have) and [“Could have” vs “might have” (in lucky escape situation)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178558/could-have-vs-might-have-in-lucky-escape-situation/178559#178559)

Comment: A good question with some good answers that should help demystify the meanings and usages of can, could, may, and might [What is the difference between 'can', 'could', 'may' and 'might'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/99957/what-is-the-difference-between-can-could-may-and-might?rq=1) and here is a question which I answered that may be of some help [“It was not to be closed” or “It should not have been closed”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194416/it-was-not-to-be-closed-or-it-should-not-have-been-closed).

Comment: If none of these posts have helped, edit your question referring and linking to any one of them, explaining where your confusion lies. That might stir up some interest in your question. Good luck!