# When to use Might & May?

Tags: british-english

Is it correct to say

"MIGHT I have a look around?
OR
"MAY" I have a look around?

Which is correct and why ?

Thanks

Comment: _Might_ typically falutes a little higher than _may_; since it's potentially counterfactual, it's more polite in a request, like using the subjunctive in Spanish: _Dame un cafe_ 'Give me a coffee' is not rude (as it would be in English), but it's not nearly as polite as _Que me de un cafe_ 'that you give[subjunctive] me a coffee'.

Comment: a very similar question was “May” & “Might”: What's the right context? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7/may-might-whats-the-right-context

Comment: Since you seem to be specifically asking for permission you should use 'may'.  If you say 'might' you're asking if the possibility exists but not for permission.  (You visit your friend's house) "May I have a look around?" versus (you come home to your own home and the construction team is there doing some work) "Anything dangerous lying around? - might I have a look around?"