# may/ might differences and nuances

Tags: grammar

Could you please explain the following, which has tormented me for quite a while. My teacher says that there are three kinds of " may/ might ".

First, the "may/might" used for assumptions with 50 percent degree certainty like " he may be drunk now , he may have been drunk yesterday ".

Second, "may/might" for concession " he might have been there but I didn't see him , he may be rich but he is unhappy ".

Third - may for permission. I think that your rich and beautiful language has more meanings of may and might.

Could you please elaborate on that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["May" & "Might": What's the right context?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7/may-might-whats-the-right-context) (see Brillig's answer).

Comment: Yes, Brillig's is an excellent answer. I note especially **"It is recommended to prefer might have over may have for a hypothetical that didn’t happen'**. One of my pet peeves is people saying 'X may not have happened' when we know perfectly well that it did.

Comment: I'd say 'three' usages is a vast oversimplification. 'In my student days, I might, on the odd occasion, pop to the market for a pot of 'Bagtree' strawberry jam' (rare frequency actions in the past). // 'You _might_ have gone to see your aunt when you were over that way' (upbraiding at a missed opportunity). // 'I might well do that' (80% probability?)  // 'Yes, I might have done ... but I chose not to' ('might' = 'had the chance / ability / power / opportunity to) ... Modal usages take many years to master.//

Comment: Lexico perhaps mirrors the three-usage approximation for 'might' [V]  most harmoniously. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/might) lists 8 usages (though different dictionaries will doubtless separate subsenses into senses differently). I can only begin to imagine how much space OED dedicates to the ultra-flexible _might_.

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: The three basic usages are a good starting structure, but be aware that "assumptions with 50 percent degree certainty" is madness. Assumptions with 0 to 100% certainty may take *may/might*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think you're right about the years it takes to master modal usages. I'm not sure that I've mastered this particular set definitively after seventy of them:-)