# Why "could" is used on future events

Tags: grammar

"Do you think we could start the meeting an hour later?"

Why is the sentence above not:

"Do you think we can start the meeting an hour later?"

Comment: It is used could for future when something still has not been decided and there is not a 100% chance of happening so. Do not ask why, that's a rule.

Comment: Where can i learn more about how to use "could"? <-- real question, but again, why "can", but not why "could"?

Comment: Can is used to express something in present tense, not future

Comment: 'Do you think we can' only asks about the physical ability and the circumstancial possibility of the event occurring. 'Do you think we should' asks about the advisability of the event. 'Do you think we could' is an invitation to participate in an agreed activity.

Comment: @sardikuka 'Do you think we can' is a question about present ability, which, if it still exists in the future, will permit an event to occur.

Comment: 'It would be advantageous if the meeting were postponed by one hour ... Is that agreeable?' May be loosely paraphrased by either 'Do you think we can start the meeting an hour later?' or 'Do you think we could start the meeting an hour later?' [note that both these also carry the 'are we able to ...' sense]. The choice of 'could' affords greater hedging, less assertiveness.

Comment: I am aware of that, still...thanks. You explained it nicely

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do I use "can" or "could"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1/when-do-i-use-can-or-could). Also addressed at [Is ... 'can' or 'could' more polite?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7414/is-either-can-or-could-more-polite).