# Can or could; modal verbs

Tags: modal-verbs

What does 'could' mean in the following sentences Or how is 'could' different from 'can' in these sentences?

I appreciate any help you can/could provide.

I will appreciate any help you can/could provide.

I would appreciate any help you can/could provide.

Does could mean 'might be able to'? That is, I doubt your ability to provide help.

Well, I know the difference between 'can' and 'could' as I've gone through many dictionaries and forums to understand all the modal verbs. I just wanted to know whether my understanding of 'could' in relation to the given sentences is correct or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do I use "can" or "could"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1/when-do-i-use-can-or-could)

Answer (score 3):

These are not just any sentences with *can* or *could*. These are **requests**, and as such they have special usages.

There is a grammatical construction for telling people what you want them to do:

- *Help me with this.*

But instead of using the imperative, the speaker has asked a question.
Using a question form is already indirect. The speaker is not asking for information. The speaker is asking for service, but indirectly, preserving
the addressee's face by not imposing a demand.

Similarly, the use of modals is more softening. The speaker does not ask for a prediction or promise:

- *Are you going to help me?*

but rather merely a question about possibility -- *can you? could you? might you be able to? do you think it's conceivable that you would?* -- these are all standard phrases by now, though the long ones are for more formal occasions.

So it's not a matter of the two modals having different senses -- and, incidentally, there's no issue of doubt involved; it's all just politeness formulas -- but rather that [modals are **very** complex](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf) and have many social and idiomatic usages that don't follow normal kinds of rules. In fact, every modal I know anything about is terribly irregular in just about every conceivable way. That's just the way they are.

Comment: A modal answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I [will] appreciate any help you can (= are able) provide.
>
> I [will] appreciate any help you could (= are possibly able to) provide.

The "could" form is a polite request as it does not assume that the amount of help that is required is capable of being given.

Compare:
"Will you open that window?" This is almost a command.

"Would you open that window?" This is the polite version.

The "will" makes no difference.

Comment: Which one is the most common, out of the given options?

Comment: @Rizan Malik The one that is most appropriate. However, you are asking for a favour - it is always best to be polite